# How do I detect the mime-type of an image that is already a resource variable?

Tags: php

Is it possible to determine the mime-type of an image resource, while it is still a resource variable? If I output the resource variable and use `mime_content_type()` or `getimagesize()`, its mime type is already set via whatever output function I use (`imagejpeg()`, `imagepng()` etc).

The reason I need to know this is to determine if the image may have transparency - if it was a JPEG, i know it can't, if it was a PNG or GIF, I know it potentially could have transparency.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you could use [getimagesizefromstring()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) it should return not only the size but an array with some information, imagetype should be what are you looking for

Answer (score 2):

I just googled for magic numbers for jpg, png and I found this site:

https://asecuritysite.com/forensics/magic

which states the following magic numbers these file types:

```
.jpg  =>  FFD8
.gif  =>  47 49 46 38
.png  =>  89 50 4E 47
```

These numbers are the values of the first n bytes of the file which work as a signature of the file type. The values are expressed in hexadecimal.

By peeking into these values you can determine the type of the file.